# Cant find Xamarin.Forms PCL Template on visual studio for mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

When I'm creating new xamarin forms application on my **visual studio for mac** I cant specify the app to be PCL or Shared. When I select template on Multiplatform >> App >> Forms App and create the project it doesnt ask me for shared or PCL. I want PCL but created project is not PCL. Any solutions, suggestions please...

Comment: use the "Blank Forms App" template.

Comment: @Jason Then by, how to implement the android and ios projects properly? is there a documentation or instructions for this

Comment: @Jason Hi jason its me again, I tried yor suggestion later I replied to you :d I saw I can select PCL now :d :d:d:d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example in Xamarin Studio, but if you are using the lastest verion of Visual Studio For Mac or Xamarin Studio,they should be identical.

Multiplatform >> App >> Blank Forms App >> Configure your Forms App

[image]

If I am not wrong, "Multiplatform >> App >> Forms App" is now a forms with template, it is slightly different with the previous version.